# only execute ONCE when DOM is mounted, but not anytime more

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Is there a way to execute a function only once, when component is mounted (like componentDidMount() ), but not execute any more when state is changing. I cannot find any efficient solution.

If I execute an AJAX to populate data, and change the state which store that data, the componentDidMount() is executed another time and the AJAX is called, so the data is populated another time... And I cannot do client/local changes persistent (like deleting positions of an array, etc).

I thought in having the data stored in variable(s) outside the component class, but I couldn't refresh the component when I need it...

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: use of Cookies or localstorage to keep a flag might help.

Comment: I see that the problem was not the execution of componentDidMount(), in fact it wasn't executing d Ajax, neither populting the data, but the render() was not refreshing the state. If I do this.forceUpdate(), after splting the array of state, it renders the view with the changes in the array (so works). But as far as I'm concerned, force the update is not a good practice...

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Stupid me, I split the array of the state, but didn't make a setState of the result:

Comment: _deleteEnvironment: function() {
      
      var envselect = $(".collection .collection-item.active").text();

      var envpos = _.findIndex(this.state.environments, {id: envselect } );
      this.state.environments.splice(envpos,1);
      this.setState({environments: this.state.environments});

      //this.forceUpdate(); //NOT NECCESARY
  },